# How to create different objects from a List of Strings?

Tags: java, oop, java-stream

I have a file with a various figures like this:

SQUARE;10

SQUARE;20

RECTANGLE;10;30

CIRCLE;10

After adding the lines to the String List, I would like it to create all the objects after one run through the list. how to do it when, for example, a rectangle has two parameters and the rest only one?

So far this is my code which works but it is buggy, because for each type of figure I have to go through the list again, I also can't use switch for this task.

```
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("figury.txt"));
    List<List<String>> list1 = new ArrayList<>();
    String s;
    while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(s.split(";"));
        list1.add(list);

    }
    list1.stream().filter(k -> k.contains("SQUARE")).forEach(i -> new Square(Integer.parseInt(i.get(1))));
    list1.stream().filter(k -> k.contains("CIRCLE")).forEach(i -> new Circle(Integer.parseInt(i.get(1))));
    list1.stream().filter(k -> k.contains("RECTANGLE")).forEach(i -> new Rectangle(Integer.parseInt(i.get(1)), Integer.parseInt(i.get(2))));
```

All figures are subClasses of abstract class Figure

Comment: Hint: streams are sort of an advanced concept. When you are learning a new language, then it makes sense to use the "base" concepts first. Like: instead of doing 3 stream calls, just iterate that list once, and then have a cascade of if statements in that ONE loop body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
        Map<String, Function<List<String>, Figure>> converters = new HashMap<>();
        converters.put("SQUARE", l -> new Square(Integer.parseInt(l.get(1))));
        // Repeat for each shape

        List<Figure> list = list1.stream().map(l -> converters.get(l.get(0)).apply(l))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Minor: naming the lambda parameter `l` is really counter intuitive. It is not a "l"ist, but a "s"tring, so why not call it s? Also: you might want to do a toUpperCase on that input, just to make sure you don't stumble over input such as "SQUARe" ;-)

Comment: `l` is actually list of strings.

Answer (score 0):

check this out :

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("figury.txt"));
        List<Object> list = new ArrayList<>();
        String s;
        while ((s = br.readLine()) != null) {
            String[] splitItems = s.split(";");
            String objectType = splitItems[0].toUpperCase();
            switch (objectType) {
                case "SQUARE" : {
                    list.add(new Square(splitItems[1]));
                    break;
                }
                case "RECTANGLE" : {
                    list.add(new Rectangle(splitItems[1], splitItems[2]));
                    break;
                }
                case "CIRCLE" : {
                    list.add(new Circle(splitItems[1]));
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    //do nothing
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: this can refactored a lot..

Comment: But still a nice answer, as it will help newbie folks reading the question to understand what needs to be done.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do in this way by using the switch case approach:**

```
list1.forEach(list -> {
            String shape = list.get(0);
            switch (shape){
                case "SQUARE":
                    System.out.println("It is square");
                    new Square(Integer.parseInt(list.get(1)));
                    break;
                case "CIRCLE":
                    System.out.println("It is circle");
                    new Circle(Integer.parseInt(list.get(1)));
                    break;
                case "RECTANGLE":
                    System.out.println("It is rectangle");
                    new Rectangle(Integer.parseInt(list.get(1)), Integer.parseInt(list.get(2)));
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        });
```

**Output:**

```
It is square
It is square
It is circle
It is rectangle
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a FigureFactory

```
class FigureFactory {
    static Figure fromStringList(List<String> list) {
        if (list.size() > 0) {
            switch(list.get(0)) {
                case "SQUARE" :
                    return new Square(Integer.parseInt(list.get(1)))
                case "CIRCLE" :
                    ....
            }
        } 
    }
}
```

Then use it like this :

```
    list1.stream().map(FigureFactory::fromStringList);
```